# Selenium WebDriver - Selecting webelements with findElements(By.xpath

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver, xpath-2.0

I have a webpage from which I have to extract a bunch of names from web elements. My idea is to extract all those elements first using "findElements(By.xpath...", something like this:

```
List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("XPATH???"));
```

All those elements have xPath pattern like this:

```
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/h2/a
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[2]/div[1]/h2/a
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[3]/div[1]/h2/a
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[4]/div[1]/h2/a
/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div[5]/div[1]/h2/a
```

As you can see the only change is in this penultimate div that is changing.
MY question is how can I write this line of code for filling a webelement list, what goes into By.xPath()?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely sure what is you are trying to achieve here.

If you want all the divs:

```
List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[1]/div[6]/div[*]/div[1]/h2/a"));
```

If not please provide me with an example of the actual elements you are trying to get.

Comment: Thanks Stratos Ion!!! This solved it, just using * for all those divs. It works now!!!

Comment: Glad it worked, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
List<WebElement> divs = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Change code portion as follows-

```
List<WebElement> someElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[11]/div[1]/div[6]/div/div[1]/h2/a"));
```

Comment: You have fixed it now........ Before you had div[1] hardcoded rather than generic div entry